# JavaScript cookies lost after closing browser

Tags: javascript, cookies

```
var input = prompt('Some input','');
if(input){
    document.cookie=`key=${input};expires=${new Date(2022,1).toUTCString()};`;
}
console.log(document.cookie);
```

The question pretty much says it all. When refreshing the page, the cookies are saved, but when closing the page and reopening it in another tab, all previous cookies are lost. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you in incognito mode? Normally you add a space between `; expires`

Comment: can you try like this? document.cookie = "doSomethingOnlyOnce=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";

Comment: OP's code works, so it must be something else that affects it

Comment: if this works, then you have problem with expires date

Comment: How come it expires in `1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z` @HenslerSoftware? I thought it would expire at Fri, `31 Jan 2020 23:00:00 GMT`. Why does it behave like this?